# Pop up For Alert

Tags: c#, java, .net, powershell, vbscript

I'm going to ask the end users to clean their cache addresses using 
`Outlook.exe /CleanAutoCompleteCache` command in outlook. 
I can create a batch file and ask them to click on it.It works, but before proceeding they should get pop up alert that running this file will delete all addresses from cache.

Comment: Sry, but I can't understand your problem?What exactly you want to do?

Comment: You should describe your problem like which programming language are you use or plan and what you think about how to do this? Please specify your question?

Comment: What is it with you people? He has a batch file that executes `Outlook.exe /CleanAutoCompleteCache`. Before this runs, he wants to ask the user if he really wants to run the command. If you cant understand it, don't put it on the OP.

Comment: Question understanding is one thing, but look at his tags. What he want to know about C# / Java aso?

Comment: I try to undestand what is the questiuon and want to specify his question. For example I couldn't relate this question with java tag?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with these people, the question wasn't immediately clear due to the wording and the addition of the plethora of tags, just because you are capable of understanding it doesnt mean everyone is, they were asking questions to increase their understanding so that they might be able to answer the OP and actually give him an answer, and since they are going out of their way to help the OP then yes, yes they can 'put it on the OP'

Answer (score 1):

If you need a `messagebox` you can add this to your powershell script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
$result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("if you run this file it will delete all addresses from your cache","Warning", 4)
if ($result -eq "Yes" )
{
  ...do work...
}
else
{
 ..do some other stuff..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the PowerShell you can create a custom confirmation dialog as [shown here](http://www.peetersonline.nl/2009/07/user-confirmation-in-powershell/):

```
param([string]$title="Confirm",[string]$message="Are you sure?")
$choiceYes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Answer Yes."
$choiceNo = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Answer No."
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($choiceYes, $choiceNo)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)
switch ($result)
{
    0 
    {
        Return $true
    }

    1 
    {
        Return $false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a little powershell script :

```
$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
$intAnswer = $a.popup("INFORM USER HERE", 0,"WARNING",1) 
If ($intAnswer -eq 6)
{ 
    //USER OK
} 
else 
{ 
    //USER CANCEL
}
```

Read [HERE](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1a386b01-b1b8-4ac2-926c-a4986ac94fed)

Comment: Thanks to all for the reply, i need to run this command from the client side outlook with the alert pop up message. the suggestion given by you all will work in powershell. but it will not work in client outlook.